# With PHP is this method of referencing database info secure?

Tags: php, mysql, database, .htaccess

In any file wherein I connect to my database, I have this line at the start of the document:

```
include ('database/data.php');
```

which consists entirely of

```
$database = mysqli_connect(host,Username,Password,Table);
```

And then in the 'database' folder, I have a .htaccess file with this:

```
<files data.php>
order allow,deny
deny from all
</files>
```

So far it's been working fine, but I need to know- is this secure?

Comment: Even better would be to store your DB credentials (and any other sensitive data) outside of the document root.

Comment: It'll be better to move that file from public directories. If your server will stop parsing PHP (eg. because of bad configuration or other problems) still no one will be able to see your database password.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you aren't printing/echoing out your database credentials, technically people can't get a hold of them.

Comment: So for all intents and purposes, this system is safe enough for people to entrust their passwords and emails to it?

Comment: Don't take my word for it, but aslong as you're encrypting their information/storing their emails and passwords securely, then yes its safe enough. Prevent exploits methods like SQL Injections, RFI, LFI, XSS, etc

Answer (score 0):

As of now you are *secure*, but do make sure all your other files are filtered from common attacks like **`RFI`**, **`SQL Injection`**. If there is an **`RFI`** (Remote File Inclusion) attack available (say in your Upload Image / Upload File (Form)) , then the attacker may upload a **`c99`** shell and delete all your files.

Comment: Any time I touch on data from $_GET or $_POST I use this function to clean it: `function test_input($data)
{
 $data = trim($data);
 $data = stripslashes($data);
 $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
 return $data;
}`

Comment: You still need to do more research, as the above two functions `somewhat` takes care of XSS, but not all attacks. Have a look here http://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.sanitize.php

Answer (score 0):

It is still under your `document_root` of your webserver, so if something happens with your webserver configuration, it might spit out your credentials. 
With this setup you won't have a problem if PHP stops and starts spitting raw text. But if the webserver fails e.g. the .htaccess does not get properly parsed, it will be vulnerable.

Better split the directory in a public and private part. Where the latter will hold your database credentials.

Comment: If Apache manages to continue serving files whilst ignoring a `<files>` directive, I'll eat my hat

Comment: Yeah true, but what if the .htaccess does not get parsed or he made a typo or renames the document?
I just believe it is better to split everything in a public and private part.

Comment: Oh, I totally agree with you (see my comment on the question) but again, if Apache manages to ignore a `.htaccess` file, my hat better be delicious

Comment: I'm more or less done with the directory (it has the database info and a function or two), so I probably won't be doing anything that could risk renaming.